# What does the orange bouncing thing in the progress bar in VLC mean?

Tags: vlc-media-player

The user guide does not cover the default GUI so I thought I'd ask here.

If I stream from an URL it seems quite clear that it has something to do with the buffer, but even when I play media that is on my HDD it's still there and moving around constantly: it moves from left to right, bounces a couple of times and then it goes the other way round.

[image]

Comment: Is there any pattern to it moving around?

Comment: Yes it moves from left to right, bounces a couple of times and then it goes the other way round.

Comment: It is read ahead caching/buffering

Comment: I don't see how the bouncing would reflect the size of the buffer, surely it would be similar to Youtube's grey bar that runs ahead of the progress marker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the animLoading bouncing thingy caused by a

```
animLoading->start();
```

without a matching

```
animLoading->stop();
```

which usually doesn't happen when the video is started, but it's on all the time bouncing for any subsequent videos in the playlist while they are playing.

to workaround this bug, I just commented out that start line (245) in

```
modules/gui/qt4/util/input_slider.cpp
```

Comment: Welp so I stumbled upon a bug without even knowing!

Answer (score 2):

The slider bar can be changed/switched to the native one

[Tools] -> [Customize Interface] -> [Time Toolbar]

- Then drag the slider down (remove it)
- Select "Native Slider"
- Drag a "Time Slider" from the list to the bar

Save...